# Cocoa: Why is my table view blank?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Why is my table view blank? It was fine until I added "initWithStyle"

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

And here is what my code looks like:

Here is my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {

NSMutableArray *jokes;
IBOutlet UITableView *jokeTableView; 


 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *jokes;
@property (retain) UITableView *jokeTableView;

@end
```

And here is my implementation file:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "Joke.h"

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize jokes;
@synthesize jokeTableView;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
[jokeTableView init];
}




- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
    self.jokes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"If you have five dollars     and Chuck Norris has five dollars, Chuck Norris has more money than you"],
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"There is no 'ctrl' button on Chuck Norris's computer. Chuck Norris is always in control."],
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"Apple pays Chuck Norris 99 cents every time he listens to a song."],
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"Chuck Norris can sneeze with his eyes open."],
                  nil];

    self.jokeTableView.rowHeight = 30.0;
    // self.jokeTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    self.jokeTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
}
return self;
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { // Saying how many sections wanted (Just     like in address, where sorts by first name)
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [jokes count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Team";  
UITableViewCell *cell = 
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
             initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
Joke *j = (Joke *)[jokes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if( j )
    cell.text = j.joke;
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; 
}

- (void)dealloc {
[jokes release];
[jokeTableView release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't think that you need to have a property jokeTableView. Keep it just IBOutlet ... remove:
@property (retain) UITableView *jokeTableView;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your view controller is being loaded from a nib, you'll need to override the `initWithCoder:` method, not `initWithStyle:`.

However, the normal solution would be to add all your custom initialization code in the awakeFromNib: method, this is called after the nib is loaded and all outlets are connected, so it makes a great place to do any initialization you need.

See the [Apple docs on `awakeFromNib:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib) for details on object instantiation from nibs. Also, if you have access to the 3.0 beta docs, do a search for `awakeFromNib:`, the updated wording gives a better explanation of which methods are called and when.

P.S. You shouldn't be calling `[jokeTableView init]` in your code, this will be done automatically when the nib is unpacked.

**Edit:** Since you are setting properties for your table view from your initialization code, this should definitely be in `awakeFromNib:`, not `initWithCoder:` or `initWithStyle:`.

Looking at the screenshot, you might also want to make sure with Interface Builder that the UITableView is placed correctly in the nib file for your view controller, and that the code (or nib) that creates your view controller is referring to the right nib file - if it were just the data for the table view that had not loaded, you would see gray lines between empty cells, not just blank white space like in that image.

Answer (score 2):

`initWithStyle` is not the same as `initWithCoder`. Your constructor probably isn't even getting called.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but that random `[jokeTableView init]` in `awakeFromNib` is certainly wrong and could cause problems like this. `init` should never be called without an attached `alloc`*, and in this case I doubt either is needed since the table view has presumably already been created elsewhere.

(* The one exception to this rule, obviously, is when you're overriding an init method and calling super.)

Comment: I agree, the TableView shouldn't have to be initialized every time it becomes visible. I also don't think this is an issue with populating the data, as you would at least see blank TableViewCells.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are initializing this controller using `initWithStyle` and you previously were calling `initWithCoder` , that is your problem.

You are loading your `self.jokes` in `initWithCoder`.  You should move that code to `viewDidLoad` or to your new `initWithStyle` method

```
// move this
self.jokes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"If you have five dollars and Chuck Norris has five dollars, Chuck Norris has more money than you"],
                                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"There is no 'ctrl' button on Chuck Norris's computer. Chuck Norris is always in control."],
                                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"Apple pays Chuck Norris 99 cents every time he listens to a song."],
                                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"Chuck Norris can sneeze with his eyes open."],
                                  nil];
```

Comment: I changed the code and init'd it in the initWithStyle. Still same problem though

Comment: You need to show the code that initializes this controller, from what is shown I can't see how this code is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[jokeTableView init];
}
```

you're already doing initialization in `initWithStyle:`

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you need to replace:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
```

(and the closing bracket)

with

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
```

Also, you shouldn't have to end a NSMutableArray with nil.

Comment: You need to end NSMutableArray with nil see http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The other part does not seem right either, viewDidLoad is called each time a view is unarchived from xib (if it is stored in xib) so you would reiinitialize the jokes everytime which is not what you want. View can get unloaded (by controller?) when memory is low and reloaded later on, I think viewDidLoad will get called each time.

Comment: @stefan your right. 

But  I did what you said, and now the TV is shown, but it wont populate... Whats wrong?

Comment: You're right about NSMutableArray--I have always used addObject to populate my arrays, which won't accept nil. The issue with reinitializing the array every time viewDidLoad is called can be dealt with my checking for any content in self.jokes first.